# Block-based editing with Quill

Tags: quill

I'm wondering if Quill will be able to support my need of showing one or more blocks of text and allow the user to edit them in the following way described below.

Some context:

What I try to achieve is presenting and allow editing of several sources in one editor while preserving the connection to the sources. This means that if a user takes a single block (call it A) with 100 characters it will look like this:

`[A 0-99]`

Now if the user add new text in the middle of this block the block needs to break to 2 blocks and a 3rd blocks will be added in the middle like so:

`[A 0-50]
[B 0-10] (10 new characters)
[A 51-99]`

There are other scenarios where the user deletes from the end of the block, in which case there is still one block only it takes fewer characters from the source.

I was wondering if Quill can be made to work in this block-based editing instead of characters-based editing as most editor do.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should create your **blot** for implement functional, that you want. You can define all behaviors that you need in **format** method of your blot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a tray